# Saving more data on socket.io object in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, socket.io, typescript-typings

I usually used to do something like `socket.username = username` when not using typescript. But now i am and when i try to save it the same way it gives me the error

```
Property 'username' does not exist on type 'Socket'
```

I know this means i need to extend it, but i have tried it like so

```
interface Socket {
        username: any
}
```

But it did not help and i also tried this,

```
interface SocketIO {
        username: any
}
```

With no luck.

Answer (score 7):

Just `socket['username'] = username` should do the trick.

If you want type safety and if you want to have autocompletion for the `username` property, you can extend the `Socket` interface.

```
interface ExtendedSocket extends Socket {
  username: string;
}
```

Then you can cast the original `Socket` to your custom type:

```
const mySocket = <ExtendedSocket>socket;
mySocket.username = 'user1'; // won't throw errors and autocomplete will work
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to add extra information to the socket object, you can add this information to **`socket.data`** object which is declared with `any` in their declaration file

Below is a snippet from `socket.d.ts` file

```
/**
* Additional information that can be attached to the Socket instance and which will be used in the fetchSockets method
*/
data: any;
```

Answer (score 3):

### More generic way

Simply update module declaration like so:

```
declare module 'socket.io' {
    interface Socket {
        username: string
    }
}
```

Now you can use w/o any cast:

```
socket.username = 'Bob'
```

Comment: Doesn't work they way it is intended

Answer (score 3):

In newer versions of Socket.IO, you can include this in the generic types.
This can then be found in socket.data.

```js
import { Server } from 'socket.io';

// Each event type should be a callback
interface ListenEvents {} // Events listened to on the server
interface ServerEvents {} // Events sent by the server
interface InterEvents {} // Events both listened to and sent by the server

interface SocketData {
    username: string;
}

const server = new Server<ListenEvents, ServerEvents, InterEvents, SocketData>(httpServer);

// ...
socket.data.username;
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, even though it used to. Is this still how you're supposed to do this?

Comment: This should still be working. I haven't used socket.io in a few months, so the usage might've changed since.

Note that this example usage would be server sided

Comment: Well the problem I'm having is that the client has no data field, i.e. I'm trying to extend the client socket, but it's not passing the extended information into the socket the server receives.

Comment: Here's a question I made describing my issue in more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76590830/server-side-socket-missing-data-stored-in-client-side-socket-typescript-socket

Answer (score 2):

This seems to accept a `socket.username="John"`:

```
declare global {
  namespace SocketIO {
    interface Socket {
      username: any
    }
  }
}
```

But a nicer solution (IMHO) would be to extend the socket interface to your own socket:

```
interface ExtSocket extends SocketIO.Socket 
{
  username: string;
}
```

Then declare the socket itself as `socket:ExtSocket;` or use an ugly cast:

`(socket as ExtSocket).username = "John";`