# Server-side socket missing data stored in client-side socket (typescript, socketio) initialized in custom namespace

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to create a socket that joins a specific room when it is connected, where the room I want it to join is set as a custom property of the client-side socket.

The idea here being that the server socket reads that custom room parameter and joins the socket to that room.

However, the server is not getting the room parameter I am setting on the client socket (i.e., no custom data is being stored in the socket the server receives on connection), and the socket doesn't work.

So on the client side I have something like

```
interface CustomSocket extends Socket {
    socket_room:string, 
};

class client_socket {
    socket:CustomSocket;

    constructor(socket_room:string){
        this.socket = <CustomSocket>io("/custom_namespace");
        this.socket.socket_room = socket_room; 

        this.socket.on(`custom_namespace:${socket_room}`,(arg) => {
            console.log(arg); 
        });
    };
};
```

And then on the server side I have something like

```
const io = new Server(server); // Express Server 
const custom_namespace = io.of("/custom_namespace"); 

custom_namespace.on("connection",(socket) => {
    console.log(socket.data.socket_room); // undefined 
    socket.join(socket.data.socket_room); // Joins undefined room 
});
```

And then the socket doesn't work properly (receives no emissions from the server).

On the other hand, if I don't assign the client socket to a custom namespace, i.e. declare the client socket as

```
this.socket = <CustomSocket>io(); // <- Assigned to global namespace
```

(vs. `this.socket = <CustomSocket>io("/custom_namespace");`), the server-side socket gets the data stored in the `socket_room` field:

```
const io = new Server(server); // Express Server 

io.on("connection",(socket) => {
    console.log(socket.data.socket_room); // Correctly prints value of socket_room set in client_socket constructor     
});
```

I don't understand how to solve this problem, or why it even exists?

Note that I strongly prefer to store the `socket_room` parameter in the client socket, instead of using an emission to tell the server what room that socket should join.

Answer (score 0):

Look into usage of the query parameter to pass data upon request. That seems to be what you want to use in this situation.

Comment: I'm using the query parameter for something else. It could work here too, but the solution/workaround I went with was having the client emit a join room message to the server, which is fine I guess. But I did submit a bug report to socketio.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the issue you are describing is the intended behavior, though. The client only passes properties that are required to maintain a connection to socket.io. You would most likely have to implement your own functionality for this, something with a custom getter and setter, where it emits an event such as 'set' with the appropriate data.